# How to pause screen recorder macOS Mojave with a keystroke?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, recording, macos-mojave

Mojave introduced a feature where I can press <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> to bring up the screen capture application, which has a control widget at the bottom:

[image: Mojave Screencap Tool]

If I place the rectangle over the area I want to capture, then click **Record**; It begins to record, but to stop the recording I must press the previous key combination again then click to stop the recording.

**Is there a way to pause the recording on the fly - prefereably using a keystroke with some visual feedback?**

This would make it easier to avoid long pauses in the screen capture of a terminal or window, and prevent having to edit the video file later.

Comment: Please request this feature on https://www.apple.com/feedback/quicktime.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any way to Pause.

You can Stop using  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Esc</kbd>   or click the [image] icon in the Menu bar.

[Apple KB - How to record the screen on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208721)